# Animating the stroke on an SVG shape doesnt work right

Tags: css, svg

I have the following SVG shape:

http://jsfiddle.net/69jf5ohb/

```
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 231.764 251.764" enable-background="new 0 0 231.764 251.764"
     xml:space="preserve">
  <circle id="line" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#000" r="50" cy="55" cx="55" fill="none"></circle>
</svg>
```

I am trying to make the dashed stroke go round, but as you'll notice in the JSFiddle, the stroke just jumps at some point. Why is this happening? What is make this not work?

I have calculated the diameter of the circle and made it spin from the total length to 0, it should work right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs because your circumference should be an integer multiple of the sum of your stroke dash array lengths. Change stroke dash-array to 10, 21.42; and you'll be set. 10 + 21.42 adds up to 31.42, which multiplied by 10 - is the circumference of your circle.

(But wouldn't it be easier to use a transform rotate?)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change **stroke-dasharray:** to 10, 24.85;

```css
#line{
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 24.85;
  stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  -webkit-animation: dash 14s linear infinite;
}
body{
  background: #fff;
}

@keyframes dash{
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
  x="0px" y="0px" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 231.764 251.764" enable-background="new 0 0 231.764 251.764"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <circle id="line" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#000" r="50" cy="55" cx="55" fill="none"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am not the expert about svg animations tho. I made it with trial and error method. I would have to read full documentation of svg properties to calculate everything and do it in "correct" way. You probably have skipped something during calculations, otherwise it would have worked correct.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the reason of why this is happening, manually getting numbers would just prevent some dynamic values do be programmed.